# C++ Variable Array length within struct

Tags: c++

hey guys i trying to write a handler for a generalised master/slave communication.
The implementation should be able to handle different communication types (USB/modbus/SPI etc.)
For every communication type a new instance of this class is created.
Each communication way has another max datalength limit. Every received packed (byte array) is mapped on a struct

```
class My_Communication
{
struct My_Struct
{
//some Header Information
byte data[max_data_length]; ///< this array has a different datalength.
}
}
```

Can i set the (const) datalength within a class constructor?

Comment: Array sizes must be known at the time of compilation (be `constexpr`; `const` is not enough). In all other cases - you are relying on compiler extensions, and are writing non standard code.

Comment: Use a `std::array<byte,max_data_length>` instead to make your life easier. In case `max_data_length` is a variable, better use a `std::vector<byte>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the array size at compile time you should use `std::vector`:

```
class My_Communication
{
  struct My_Struct
  {
    //some Header Information
    std::vector< byte > data;
  };
};
```

If you know the size at compile time then use std::array in a templated class:

```
class My_Communication
{
  template < size_t DataSize >
  struct My_Struct
  {
    //some Header Information
    std::array< byte, DataSize > data;
  };
};
```

Comment: the array size is known at compile time. But it has to be passed via the constructor to the class. If i got this correctly, i'll need an initialiser list. The reason i'm not using vector is that i need sizeof(my_struct) to return the actual size. For Vector this does not work because the actuall content of the vector is located on the heap right

Comment: Thx for your reply. The size is known at compile time. I'd prefer to use a initialiser list. However this does not work. `array<int , test_array_size> test_array`; (where test_array_size is a const initialised in an init. list). I'm getting the compiler error that i can only use static const members and not const instance members as an array size. Is there any way arond this?

Comment: @JuliusCaesar, no there isn't, if it's known at compile time then you can make it a constant and it'll work otherwise you'll need to use `std::vector`